# knitr chunk option eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE, include=FALSE

Tags: r, knitr

I use RMarkdown and `knitr` for dynamic report generation.

When knitting a document, I would like to have the code from an Rmarkdown chunk included in the knitted document and run the code -- but *not* show the output. That is, I would like to be able to do what this code suggests:

```
eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE, include=FALSE
```

... and make `knitr` run the code (`eval = TRUE`), show the code (`echo = TRUE`), but not show the lengthy output (attempted with `include = FALSE`), but my attempts fail.

Does such an option exist with `knitr`? Or is it possible to program this with a `hook` in `knitr`?

(using only `include=FALSE` runs the code, but does not show the code.)

(Notification of cross-posting: I posted this question at RStudio support a week ago, but have not received any answer indicating yes or no, or how to achieve what I want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am understanding your problem correctly, the issue is the `include=F` option. You should try instead to use `results = "hide"`. Here is how you can set it at the beginning of your Rmarkdown document so that it is the default setting.

````
```{r}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
```
````

Comment: Thanks. One may also have to add `message = FALSE, warning = FALSE`, if warnings are expected and not indicating an error. (I would use these commands in individual chunks only, not globally)