# call a variable in environnment

Tags: r, sweave

I would like to know how to display the result of a variable that is in the environment

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

Hello,

\input{test2.Rnw}


\end{document}
```

test2.Rnw

```
\section{test}

<<eval=TRUE, echo=F>>=
paste0("my variable v is worth: ", v)
@
```

When I compile I get this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the knitr package inside your Rmarkdown code. Check https://riptutorial.com/r/topic/4334/r-in-latex-with-knitr and also this SO Q&A : [knitr chunk option eval=TRUE, echo=TRUE, include=FALSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42596609/knitr-chunk-option-eval-true-echo-true-include-false)

Comment: It's not a Rmarkdown code, it's R sweave. When i use _\Sexpr{paste0("my variable v is worth: ", v)}_  I get this error: _! Undefined control sequence._ When i put _<<>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(eval = TRUE, echo = TRUE, results = "hide")
@_  i get this error: _! Missing $ inserted._